# SharePoint Online 'GetListItemChangesSinceToken' API Issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

We've encountered an issue with our Outlook add-in that uses the SharePoint online REST API 'GetListItemChangesSinceToken' on document libraries. Recently, in various locations, this request fails with a 'System.ArgumentException' on the server side, impacting the functionality of our add-in across multiple organizations.

The issue is reproducible by uploading a specific document ('capitalization table.xlsx') to different SharePoint document libraries, but not when the same file is uploaded to OneDrive. We need assistance in diagnosing and resolving this issue.

Attachments:

Sample Request:

```
POST https://ravenwooddemo.sharepoint.com/projectsandmeetings/projects/_api/Web/GetList(@a1)/GetListItemChangesSinceToken?@a1='%2fprojectsandmeetings%2fprojects%2fRavenwood+HQ' HTTP/1.1

{"query":{"ViewFields":"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /></ViewFields>","RowLimit":"1000"}}
```

Sample Response:

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value does not fall within the expected range."}}}
```